# RealTek sound card driver not working with Windows XP SP2

Tags: windows-xp, audio

I’m running Windows XP SP2 and it has no sound. No it’s not on mute. I have recently got a new hard drive and had sound working fine. I have tried to install the driver for the sound card (three times), but I get the BSoD (blue screen of death) halfway through the install, the driver was from RealTek… now here is the hardware IDs: `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_27DE&SUBSYS_01AD1028&REV_01`

Comment: hardware ID? give us the make model of card. Does the card even have XP drivers or are you trying to use Win7/Win8 drivers on XP? If you want compatibility with XP you need a driver for Vista.

Comment: SP2? you really ought to upgrade. I'm wondering if the new drivers were even tested on something that old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AC'97 Audio Codecs](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) get 18295k size setup.

If you systemboard at VIA chipset download [VIA Hyperion Pro Driver Package](http://download.viatech.com/DriverDownloadSubmitAjaxSvl)